# Delete matching primary key values between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

### The Problem:

I'm trying to delete rows in a table if the primary key values in a row match a row in a different table. For example, say I have table `TABLE1` and table `TABLE2` with primary keys indicated by *:

```
TABLE1 before:
Col A*| Col B*| Col C| Col D
__________________________
1      a         x      x 
2      a         x      x 
3      a         x      x 
3      b         x      x 

TABLE2:
Col A*| Col B*| Col C| Col D
__________________________
1      a         y      y 
4      a         y      y 
5      a         x      x
```

I want to delete any rows from `TABLE1` where the primary key values (Col A/Col B) match `TABLE2`, then copy over all data in `TABLE2` to `TABLE1`. In this case, the first row of `TABLE1` has matching primary key values with `TABLE2`, so only that row would be deleted:

```
TABLE1 after:
Col A*| Col B*| Col C| Col D
__________________________
2      a         x      x 
3      a         x      x 
3      b         x      x
```

### Code so far:

The following query seems to work for selecting the values to be deleted:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.A = TABLE2.A
AND TABLE1.B = TABLE2.B)
```

And to delete the rows I believe I could change it to DELETE FROM instead of SELECT * FROM. However, I want to try and avoid hardcoding the primary key columns so that I could use this query on different tables and just change the table names.

I have the following query that will select the names of the primary key columns:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM (
SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cols.table_name = 'TABLE1'
AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position)
```

But I'm not sure how to combine this with my other statement (or if this is possible). I'm also open to other ideas on any other possible solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of/tried [dynamic sql](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I have not used dynamic sql before, but I will take a look at it and see if I can use it somehow to solve this. I found the oracle documentation on dynamic sql here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011 . Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm).

Dynamic SQL lets you select columns and other things on the fly by building the query, rather than having a stored procedure that is executed every time.  There are some challenges, but it can be a useful tool where necessary.  You do need to be somewhat more careful about SQL injection attacks with it.

Comment: I ended up using [MyBatis' dynamic sql](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) since I was using Java. But anyway I will accept your answer. Thanks for the help.